# Ganymed vs JSch?

Tags: java, ssh

I am currently evaluating opensource tools for ssh and http tunneling in Java. I have come down to two contenders: [Ganymed](http://www.cleondris.ch/opensource/ssh2/) and [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). Does anyone know the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my take on both after using them at length:

- JSch: Ultimately more flexible, but at the cost of being much more low level. It is also not well documented (no JavaDoc tags) but is none-the-less very stable.
- Ganymed: Provides good support for most of the standard SSH operations you might need (port forwarding, reverse port forwarding, SCP file copying etc.). Documentation is decent in the form of Javadoc of primary public classes.

The biggest difference, in my view, is that Ganymed provides a more intuitive and encapsulated API that maps directly to high level SSH operations.

//Nicholas

Comment: There is javadoc for Jsch written by paul here http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/.Nice one

Comment: @Nicholas I assume you are sarcastic

Comment: @hrishirc  No. Why ? Bad comment, or bad answer ?

Comment: no, no! Not a bad answer at all! I thought the comment was sarcastic. Because the documentation certainly isn't good. I had huge trouble finding something as elemetary as what the exitStatus of the process returned when. The docs are terrible.

Comment: Gotcha. I just referenced that specific link because the author seems to have gone to the trouble of enriching the javadoc a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Ganymed.
  But I have used JSch extensively for remote login and script executions. I used Google Expect4j with JSch for executing scripts on remote machines in expect mode(send/wait). You can get the whole output of executed command or scripts in your code using JSch/Expect4j/Closures.

Thanks.